# One or more properties contains invalid values when create service principal for Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm having trouble to create service principal for Azure Container Registry. It keep telling me that **One or more properties contains invalid values**,

I'm using the [code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-service-principal#create-a-service-principal) from the official web site. It was working several days before.

**What I've tried so far**

1. Verify all variables in the code and make sure all of them are valid
2. Delete the service principle via Azure Portal

Have you ever encounter this issue? What elements could result this error?

Comment: Delete service principle via Azure Portal does not work, delete from Azure CLI solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Delete service principle via Azure Portal does not work, delete from Azure CLI solved the problem